# Writing a file to a custom created directory on Oracle Amazon-RDS

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I can connect to the database via sqlplus

```
sqlplus stepdba/<password>@steprds.<rds-hash-here>.<region>.rds.amazonaws.com:1521/STEP
```

and I am trying to write to a file.

According to [AmazonRDS documentation regarding Oracle](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.Oracle.CommonDBATasks.html), create directory must be done with `rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.create_directory('MY_DIR');` which I have done.

To write to a file, I do the following:

```
DECLARE
    fileHandler UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
BEGIN
   fileHandler := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('MY_DIR', 'test.txt', 'W');
   UTL_FILE.PUTF(fileHandler, 'Writing TO a file\n');
   UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(fileHandler);
END;
/
```

Which result in an error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_FILE", line 536
ORA-29283: invalid file operation
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

If I try to write to an Oracle provided directory `DATA_PUMP_DIR`, the above snippet executes correctly and the file is written.

The privileges to the two directories are the same

```
select grantee, privilege from dba_tab_privs where table_name='DATA_PUMP_DIR' and grantee = 'STEPDBA';
select grantee, privilege from dba_tab_privs where table_name='MY_DIR' and grantee = 'STEPDBA';
```

In the Amazon-RDS case, we can not manipulate the file/directory permissions on the OS level.

I seem to be missing something, any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: What path does MY_DIR point to? Check in DBA_DIRECTORIES. Can you check if the path exists?

Comment: `rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.create_directory` will make `MY_DIR` point to `/rdsdbdata/userdirs/01` (so, yes, Oracle thinks, that the path exist). According to the documentation it is possible to make 10 directories. Filesystem access to `/rdsdbdata/userdirs/01` is NOT possible, i.e. `chmod` on this directory is not the way to solve this (or, it is not possible for me as an RDS user, to change the permissions on this directory nor check if the directory actually does exist on the underlying filesystem)

Comment: Begs the question what's the point of writing to a file if you cannot access it. Anyway, who owns the MY_DIR directory (from DBA_DIRECTORIES), and are you running the PLSQL block that fails as a different user? Can you check if READ,WRITE priv has been granted to MY_DIR?

Comment: READ, WRITE privs granted to MY_DIR and DATA_PUMP_DIR are as expected. The user that created MY_DIR is the one trying to write to it. I am trying to reach out to other Amazon RDS users that might have encountered the same problem and solved it.

Answer (score 1):

Hi I had exactly the same problem. Solved it by using higher version of Oracle software: Oracle SE One 11.2.0.4.v4 
One that was causing the problems was Oracle SE One 11.2.0.4.v3

Comment: I am happy to hear that I'm not the only one with the above problem! I ended up writing the files I needed writing, in the DATA_PUMP directory.